# How to load only changed portion of YAML file in Ruamel

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml library to load and process YAML file.

The YAML file can get updated after I have called

```
yaml.load(yaml_file_path)
```

So, I need to call l`oad()` on the same YAML file multiple times.

Is there a way/optimization parameter to pass to loader to load only the new entries in the YAML file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such facility currently built into ruamel.yaml.

If a file consists of multiple YAML documents, you can optimize the loading, by splitting the file on the document marker (`---`). This is fairly trivial and then  you can load a single document from start to finish.

If you only want to reload parts of a document things get more difficult. If there are anchors and aliases involved, there is no easy way to do this as you may need a (non-updated) anchor definition in an updated part that needs an alias. If there are no such aliases, and you know the structure of your file, and have a way to determine what got updated, you can do partial loads and update your data structure. You would need to do some parsing of the YAML document, but if you only use a subset of YAML possibilities, this is often possible.

E.g. if you know that you only have simple scalar keys at the root level mapping of a YAML document, you can parse the document and extract non-indented strings that are followed by the value indicator. Any such string that is not in your "old" data structure is a new key and its value should be parsed (i.e. the YAML document content until the next non-indented string).

The above is far less trivial to do for any added data that is not added at the root level (whether mapping or sequence).
Since there is no indication within the YAML specification of the complexity of a YAML docment (i.e. whether it includes anchors, alias, tags etc), any of this is less easy to built in ruamel.yaml itself.

Without specific information on the format of your YAML document, and what can get updated, specific implementation details cannot be given. I assume however that you will not update and write out the loaded data, if that is so, make sure to use

```
 yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
```

when possible as this will get you much faster loading times than the default round-trip loader provides.